# Ending the Economic Spiral (USA)

Tags: inflation

In the US, there is the following spiral:

1. Workers get mandated wage increases.
2. Businesses, retail and service industry raise prices to account for the wage hike.
3. Workers can't afford stuff because of the raise in prices, so we go to step #1.
   (Enter at any step.)

How is this spiral stopped?

There seems to be a longer duration for wage increases for the exempt group.

In over 10 years, I've seen fast-food restaurants go from $5.00USD to now over $12.00.  Groceries have gone from $100 to over $200 (for a shopping cart full).

I'm wondering if my pay increases have been for merit or are they only to compensate for the spiral.